# Run commands on mac with java code

Tags: java, macos

I have a java application in which i need to run the commands as we do on the terminal using the java code.How can i achieve this please suggest.

I Used this code when doing it on windows :-

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: You can do the exact same thing on a Mac (with different commands, obviously).

Comment: java is platform independent, just command aren't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

All you need to do is change the commands to Mac OS X commands.